# Alert only people that have been in the room recently for chat events

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, notifications

Chat pops up a notification anytime a scheduled event in a room you're interested in is about to start. Unfortunately, it defines "room you're interested in" as "room you've been in, ever", and there appears to be no way to tell it otherwise.

I've been in quite a few chat.SE rooms for sites I'm not actually interested in, so now every week I'm told that SF is discussing recommendations, DIY is doing "Project Update Thursday", etc.

Can it be changed so either:

- Chat only alerts people that have been in the room recently
- Chat lets you opt out of receiving notifications for certain scheduled events

Comment: yes, *please*! (:

Comment: I was about to say "I'm amazed this hadn't been requested earlier", but then I noticed this was a month old. I know some folk on the Bridge who'd love this too.

Comment: @GraceNote Adding a bounty did nothing, but adding a screenshot got me two upvotes in 10 minutes

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about this... *takes notes for userscript*

Comment: How is this not fixed?! @Tim Are you adding something to the userscript to suppress these? If not I'm writing something to just hide all event notifications permanently

Comment: Yeah, it's on my to-do list, I can probably sneak it in tonight.

Comment: ...err, this week (I started, but need to finish the updater first).

Comment: @TimStone Ever update the script?  I'd love to have this right about now.

Comment: @casperOne I had concerns about the implementation due to userscript limitations, and have been working on other things since then, so not yet. But I'll make a point to revisit it as soon as possible.

Comment: @TimStone No obligations, everything you've done so far is greatly appreciated.  It's more their end, we shouldn't have to fight the system like this to opt out; this isn't Google, Javascript is not the answer to *everything*. =)

Comment: Please, man! Please!

Comment: [Please please please pleeaaaase](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwGNEE4dVqc)

Comment: The notifications for the chat casts are getting particularly annoying.

Comment: Yep, would be pretty nice to not get bothered by this just because I was browsing rooms for other sites one weekend :/.

Comment: @TimStone Have you had time to look at scripting this?

Comment: @Gilles It's actually on my to-do list for this weekend. I've started getting harassed by notifications myself, so I thought up a way to properly take care of this, and now just have to commit it to code. Will keep you informed of the progress.

Comment: @Tim any updates? Its been a month...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138204/im-puzzled-as-to-why-i-need-to-get-a-notification-of-c-chat?lq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> it defines "room you're interested in" as "room you've been in, ever"

Not quite; the definition was "room you've *spoken* in, ever, or are in right now". But I agree, that's too broad of a definition. Just because you wanted to yell at a sysadmin once* doesn't mean that one year later, you want to be notified of the "Panel discussion: vim vs. emacs for config file editing" event.

So from now on, the definition of "room you're interested in" is as follows:

- Either you're in the room right now,
- or you have ever spoken in this room, and at least one of these two is true:

  - the last time you spoke here was less than 30 days ago, or
  - the last time you were in the room was less than 7 days ago.

<sub>* You should never yell at a sysadmin. Sysadmins are the backbone of our work. Love ya, Kyle, George, and Pete! Please don't take away my VPN account.</sub>

Comment: Much better way to handle this, thank you

Comment: Is this live? I'm still getting alerts for rooms I haven't been in for ages; I got an alert for one of the religion sites a few days ago, and just now one for DIY

Comment: @MichaelMrozek The longer I stare at this code, the less I understand why you where notified. [status-no-clue-so-far]. I'll keep thinking; please also let me know when it happens again.

Comment: @balpha I just got one for "[Parashat Hashavu'a Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam?tab=schedule)" (I joined the room right after by accident, but until then I can't even remember the last time I was in that room, and I don't think I've ever spoken in there)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek You spoke [exactly once](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2712862); clearly you're very interested in the room ;p

Comment: [*sobs*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rylqs.png)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek If it helps: I just had an idea. If it proves to be correct, I'll ram my head against the wall a few thousand times and let you know afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I'm back from ramming, so it shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: Aha... so the reason I keep receiving weekly notifications about a certain event I'm not even remotely interested in, is because I enter the room to see if I can somehow get rid of the notification every time it happens. That's a bit of a bummer, but now I know.