# I'm puzzled as to why I need to get a notification of C# chat

Tags: discussion, chat, notification-bar

Why did I get a notification in chat about ".NET Programming Puzzles" in C# chat?

Does it have to be so intrusive? Do we need it at all? I mean I'm in another chatroom which has nothing to do with c#.

[image: i hate puzzles]

**UPDATE**

Ok I might have been in that room at some point. Any way to disable it?

Also see the [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108485/let-users-opt-out-of-scheduled-event-notifications) with [status-completed]. Completed how? Where do I opt out? How to prevent receiving pings I don't want?

**UPDATE2**

OK it is impossible to opt out. Can I make this into a [feature-request]? As it currently works it shows a "huge" banner and I think it also pings me. While there is a huge banner. Wouldn't it be possible to just add an extra link stating: "do not bug me again with these banners from this room"?

Comment: Your initial reaction is interesting.

Comment: Anyway, I imagine you'd love for this to be implemented, but it obviously hasn't been done yet: [Let users opt out of scheduled event notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108485/let-users-opt-out-of-scheduled-event-notifications)

Comment: Glad you like my reaction. Almost as intrusive as the notifications :)  What's that status on that one? Not deferred / declined / finished?

Comment: The notifications should only show for those that have signed up for the event, IMO.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Over time my reaction has built-up to that

Comment: You're getting it because you entered that room at some point in the past. And, best I can tell, you will now get them *foreverrrr*

Comment: I don't understand your edit -- are you saying that you received another notification despite not having been in the room?

Answer (score 6):

You received the notification because you have once [talked in that room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1775863#1775863) (contrary to what random says, just *having been* there wouldn't have caused this).

Now of cause those were two messages posted more than half a year ago, which can hardly be interpreted as "this is a room you're interested in", thus [by the new "when will you be notified" logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138238/115866), you wouldn't have received that notification.

Comment: Guess that's the difference between a voyeur and someone who opens their mouth