# How can I get out of a chat-room for real

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

When I check chat link in my stackoverflow account it says:
"a list of rooms you are currently in, recently active rooms first"
and there is a room in which I am available.
How can I exit the room and remove it from the room list of my account > Rooms > mine ?

Actually I can leave the room but I am receiving events about the room everyday. and that is annoying.

Answer (score 8):

Enter the room and click the "leave" button:

[image]

Comment: Actually I did that but I am receiving events about the room everyday. and that is annoying.

Comment: AFAICT, that's by-design. You have to be out of the room for several days before people and events can no longer notify you. The main reason is that regulars that come every day will still logout during certain hours and will "leave" the room. But they still want to be notified of events.

Comment: So in other words `leave` won't leave...yet.

Comment: The exact rules for this are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138238/153008), @user7116.

Answer (score 0):

After leaving a chat-room, you still receive notifications about the events about the room everyday. But after a while, say 10 days or more, it will stop notifying you.